# How to fix Inside Node-Red IbmIot Node does not display Bluemix as an Authentication Option?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, node-red

The sentence is simple and problem is well explained, after making a Node-Red application in IBM Watson and a sucefull Watson Iot Platform connection inside Node-Red inside IBM Iot Node i can not chose Bluemix Authentication as i supose to.

Answer (score 1):

The Watson IoT nodes in Node-RED will only list 'Bluemix Authentication' if you have created an instance of the Watson IoT Platform service **and** you have connected the service to your application via the IBM Cloud dashboard.

If it cannot find any connected services, it will not provide that option and it will prompt you to provide a manually generated API Key.

To check the connection, log into https://cloud.ibm.com and navigate to your Node-RED application's dashboard page.

On that page click the 'connections' tab down the left-hand side.

On the connections page you should see a list of connected services. At a minimum you should see an instance of Cloudant. If your Watson IoT Platform service is not listed, click the 'Create connection' and select it from the list.

You should then restart your application (it should prompt you to do so automatically). Once it has restarted you *should* then have the Bluemix auth option available in the IBMIoT nodes.

Comment: Please make sure you accept this answer to confirm it solved the problem for you.